# How to combine a list of exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, guava

Is there any way I can combine a list of throwables? I have a list of ListenableFutures, each of which will capture exception (if any) and keep it in a Result instance. Finally, I want to throw an exception if any of the Result of the ListenableFutures contains a throwable. The issue is how to combine multiple throwables, because there could be multiple futures that fail?

```
List<ListenableFuture<Result>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
futureList.add(future1);
futureList.add(future2);
futureList.add(future3);

ListenableFuture<List<Result>> future = futureFutures.successfulAsList(futureList);

return Futures.transform(future, new Function<List<Result>, FinalResult>() {
      @Override
      public FinalResult apply(List<Result> resultList) {
        List<Throwable> throwableList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Result result : resultList) {
            if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
                throwableList.add(result.getThowable());
            }
        }

        if (!throwableList.isEmpty()) {
           // Is there something like below that I can combine a list
           // of throwables and throw it?
           Throwable.propagateList(throwableList); // ?????????
        }
        .....
        return finalResult;
      }
    },
    MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no exception that means "multiple things went wrong", but there's nothing stopping you from creating one. Exceptions are just objects, and they can have members, including something like `List<Throwable> getCauses()`.

Comment: In a certain sense, Java 7's `Throwable.getSuppressed()` also represents multiple failures

Comment: @TavianBarnes But that returns just an array.

Comment: There's `addSuppressed` though which in my case was exactly what I needed in a similar scenario.